# how i can find the next point on slope when the point can be changed?

Tags: linear-algebra

iam try to find the next point on the same slope of an line 
i I had a problem when I tried to add A small number to find the next point add it the next point The distance has become very large 
i try on this formula:

```
          slope = (P2.Y - P1.Y) / (P2.X - P1.X);
          nx2 = P2.X +add;
          ny2 = P2.Y+ slope * add;
```

The nx2 is the next x , ny2 is the next y 
and p1,p2 is the point1 and point2;
add : is the number i want to add in this case i used 18

so i used this formula in this  exmaple
this tow point ***{X=517, Y=336}--{X=505, Y=530.5}***
the next point is ***{x=535,y=44} i just add 18 for ***
but on othe point the distance is normal but on other point like this distance be very far

thank you

Comment: Was $336$ a typo?  Why are you so willing to accept that that a line will drop nearly $200$ in $12$ steps but find it so hard to believe it drops $300$ in $18$ steps.  They are bot the same amount.

Answer (score 1):

The slope can be calculated by either

$\frac {530.5 - 336}{505-517} = \frac {194.5}{-12}= -16 \frac 5{24}$.

Or by $\frac {336 - 44}{517- 535} = \frac {292}{-18}=-16 \frac 29$.

Or by $\frac {530.5 - 44}{505-535} = \frac {486.5}{-30} = -16 \frac 7{60}$.

These slopes are no exact but they all are aproximately $-16.2$ which means for every one you go over you go down $16.2$.

So to go from $x =517;y = 535$ to $x = 535$ you go over $18$.  So you expect to go down $18*16.2 = 291.6$.  So you go down from $y = 336$ to $y = 336-291.6 = 44.4$.  Which is *very* close to where we did end up at $y= 44$.

"but on othe point the distance is normal but on other point like this distance be very far"

That because $-16.2$ is a very steep slope.  Going over $12$  ($517-505= 12$) means going down nearly $200$ ($336 - 530.5= -194.5$).  And going over $18$ $(535-517$) means going down nearly $300$ ($44-336=-292$).  This is consistent.  $18$ is $1\frac 12$ times $12$ and $-292$ is (about) $1\frac 12$ times $-194.5$.

Comment: i just didn't understand what i should to d

Comment: What do you *want* to do?  I don't understand what you are asking.  If you add another 18 to go to $553$ you should subtract another 292 to $-248$.  For each one you go over you must drop down 16.2.

Comment: what i should do to make distance litle 
that's exatlly what i want

Comment: Make your horizontal move small.  Go from $505$ to $505.1$ and you should only drop $1.62$  from $530.5$ $528$.  Or go from $505$ to $505.5$ and you should only drop $8.1$ from $530.5$ to $522.4$.  .... For every unit you go horizontally, you drop $16.2$.  That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is doing what it should.  Your first two points have an $x$ difference of $12$ and a $y$ difference of about $-200$.  The third point is $18$ away in $x$, so the $y$ difference should be about $\frac {18}{12}(-200)=-300$ and it is.

Comment: i just didn't understand what i should to do

Comment: Your calculations are correct.  Maybe you need to make smaller horizontal steps.  Maybe you need to adjust your expectations.  Maybe you need not to continue on the same line.  You have made clear it is "too far" but not what you are willing to give up to get what you want.